# Does dropbox.com have special permissions from facebook to accomplish the sharing feature?

Tags: facebook, api, dropbox, sharing

I am trying to accomplish a sharing feature exactly like the one on dropbox.com

I have tried a number of things to get the app to work in the same way and I have not found a solution through the FB api.

My question requires a simple yes or no answer, but feel free to elaborate.

Does dropbox.com have some special privileges from Facebook that allows them to achieve their share with facebook friends feature?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like it would be more useful to ask how to achieve said functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately yes the "Send Message" ability is reserved for specific partners only.

Found [this post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/291/) from some time ago that still holds true today... "While we currently don't allow applications to send messages through this API, we're always thinking about new functionality to offer through Facebook Platform."

Couple options...

- It's a different UX and doesn't work on mobile, but if you're on the desktop you can use the [Send Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/).
- Otherwise, closest thing I can think of is the Facebook Chat API, but that might be a stretch depending on what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing like "Send Message" ability is reserved for specific partners only.

In Dropbox they are sending an email to the particular user with their facebook email address (eg.username@facebook.com)

You can see this email address in your facebook General Account Settings. and you can see this note below it which says:

"Your Facebook email is based on your public username. Email sent to this address goes to Facebook Messages."

You just need to retrive the user's email id and their friend's username....

and you can send attachments along with it as well....!!